# How to get a web page input datas?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Am very New to Web Page Development.

In my website i have the help page like Name, Email ID, Contact No, Comment and Submit Button Suppose i entered the data in the help page , then i press submit button means that entered data's should sent to the email account

```
For Example

Help Page

Name - Raja
Email - raja@gmail.com
Contact - 98763214
Comments - Good web page

Then I pressed Send button means, the above entered data should send to this email account
support@it.com with the same format.
```

Need Code Help or Script Help

Comment: You will need some code on the server side for this to work. What environment are you going to host this in / what scripting languages might be available on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [FormMail](http://www.scriptarchive.com/download.cgi?s=formmail&c=txt&f=FormMail.pl)

you should set these variables in formmail.pl

```
@referers = ('yourdomain.com','ip_number');
```

look at [this](http://www.scriptarchive.com/readme/formmail.html#referers)
and

```
@recipients = ('^support\@it\.com');
```

look at [this](http://www.scriptarchive.com/readme/formmail.html#recipients)
and

```
$mailprog = '/usr/lib/sendmail -i -t';
```

which is the path of sendmail in your system. if you're not sure where is your sendmail path, use the following command at your unix prompt:

```
which sendmail
```

This will tell you where sendmail is on your system. If it says it could not find it, just ask your system administrator.

after configured formmail.pl, put it in cgi-bin folder.

here is an example of a form using formmail.pl ( recipient field is required )

```
<form name="myform" action="http://yourdomain.com/cgi-bin/test.pl" method="GET">
    <input type=hidden name="recipient" value="support@it.com">
    <input type=textarea name="mytext"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

for more information about how to use formmail, go [here](http://www.scriptarchive.com/readme/formmail.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like Jørn Schou-Rode said, you really need to use a server-side programming language to catch and process the form data. The options are numerous - PHP, ASP, .NET, ColdFusion, Java, Ruby... the list goes on. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting as a starting point.

I remember starting out in web development and wanting to do the same thing but you really are now getting into more advanced areas of development (beyond simple client-side HTML/CSS/JavaScript coding).